# Issues on End point information of wcf services

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I'm not getting end point information in the user interface(winforms) of app.config file

i added service reference like this right-click on the project name-Add-Add Service Reference-http://localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc-GO-OK
my user interface app.config file came like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings />
     <client />
   </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

I tried with svcutil tool using visual studio command prompt ,im getting the error as Access to the path is denied

```
C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>svcutil.exe http://localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc?wsdl
```

My wsdl code

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"        xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Skillgun_App" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun"/>
<xs:element name="Chapters_Names">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sub_topic_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Chapters_NamesResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun" minOccurs="0" name="Chapters_NamesResult" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfChapterNames"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Paper_ids">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chapter_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Paper_idsResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun" minOccurs="0" name="Paper_idsResult" nillable="true" type="q2:ArrayOfPaper_Ids"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Qtions_data">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paper_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Qtions_dataResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun" minOccurs="0" name="Qtions_dataResult" nillable="true" type="q3:ArrayOfQtions_data"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}- [\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun">
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfChapterNames">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ChapterNames"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfChapterNames"/>
<xs:complexType name="ChapterNames">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_nameofChapter" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_no_of_papers" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_no_of_questions" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ChapterNames"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfPaper_Ids">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Paper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:Paper_Ids"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfPaper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPaper_Ids"/>
<xs:complexType name="Paper_Ids">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Paper_Id" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Paper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:Paper_Ids"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfQtions_data">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Qtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:Qtions_data"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfQtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfQtions_data"/>
<xs:complexType name="Qtions_data">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Answer" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAnswers"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_answer_choice" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_answer_explaination" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_desc" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_help_text" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_id" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapter" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Qtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:Qtions_data"/>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAnswers">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Answers" nillable="true" type="tns:Answers"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="ArrayOfAnswers" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAnswers"/>
<xs:complexType name="Answers">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Choice" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Answers" nillable="true" type="tns:Answers"/>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Chapters_Names"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Chapters_NamesResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Paper_ids"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Paper_idsResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Qtions_data"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Qtions_dataResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="ISkillgun_App">
<wsdl:operation name="Chapters_Names">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_Names"  message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_NamesResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Paper_ids">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_ids" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_idsResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="Qtions_data">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_data" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_dataResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:service name="Skillgun_App"/>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My svc code

```
namespace Skillgun
{    
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISkillgun_App
{
    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "mobile/chapters/{sub_topic_id}/app")]
    List<ChapterNames> Chapters_Names(string sub_topic_id);

    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "mobile/papers/{chapter_id}/app")]
    List<Paper_Ids> Paper_ids(string chapter_id);

    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "mobile/questions/{paper_id}/app")]
    List<Qtions_data> Qtions_data(string paper_id);        
  }
}
namespace Skillgun
{    
public class Service1 : ISkillgun_App
{
    private string strConnection = .....
     public List<ChapterNames> Chapters_Names(string sub_topic_id)
    {
        List<ChapterNames> chptrsdetails = new List<ChapterNames>();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("skillgun_mobile_app_Qtions_data", cn))
            {                    
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
                try
                {
                    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@topic_or_paper_id", SqlDbType.Int);
                    p1.Value = "chapters_data";
                    p2.Value = sub_topic_id;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
                    cmd.Parameters["@username"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
                    cmd.Parameters["@password"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@package_name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                    cmd.Parameters["@package_name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader drtopics = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (drtopics.Read())
                    {
                        ChapterNames qbsubchapter = new ChapterNames();
                        qbsubchapter.Qbc_id = (int)drtopics["qbc_id"];
                        qbsubchapter.Qbc_nameofChapter = drtopics["qbc_nameofChapter"].ToString();
                        qbsubchapter.Qbc_no_of_papers = (int)drtopics["qbc_no_of_papers"];
                        qbsubchapter.Qbc_no_of_questions = (int)drtopics["qbc_no_of_questions"];

                        chptrsdetails.Add(qbsubchapter);
                    }
                    drtopics.Close();

                    cn.Close();

                    string topic_username = cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value.ToString();
                    string topic_password = cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value.ToString();
                    string topic_package_name = cmd.Parameters["@package_name"].Value.ToString();                        
                    bool result = check_user(topic_username, topic_password, topic_package_name);

                    if (result == true)                                              
                        return chptrsdetails;                        
                    else
                        return null;
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        cn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

similar for remaining 2 methods

Comment: Do you have a wsdl? Can you see the wsdl on your browser when you go to http://localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc?wsdl

Comment: when i execute the wcf service in techpalle website i got message like this                                                                                                         To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:


svcutil.exe http://localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc?wsdl
You can also access the service description as a single file:

http://localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: Ok. Good. So when you click on  localhost:2850/TechpalleNew/Skillgun_App.svc?singleWsdl can you actually see your wsdl?

Comment: Then start a brand new ConsoleApplication project and do what you did before to add service reference to your console application. Make sure your wcf service is running while you add references.

Comment: i require windows form application to interact with wcf service Sir...

Comment: Console app is for you to test the process of adding references. Once you know for sure that the references can be added to your console app, there is no reason for your winforms app to fail.

Comment: Sir for console app also  app.config is not showing system.service model tag

Comment: Can you show your wsdl here?

Comment: Now i posted the wsdl code sir

Comment: See my answer below. The issue is in your wcf service. It hasn't exposed necessary bindings. If you re-create your service using the code I have given below, you will be able to add web service reference to your client without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image][image: This is how your app.config will look like.]Your wsdl is not correct.

Use below code to create your wcf service.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Skillgun
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ChapterNames", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun")]
    public partial class ChapterNames : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private int Qbc_idField;

        private string Qbc_nameofChapterField;

        private int Qbc_no_of_papersField;

        private int Qbc_no_of_questionsField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int Qbc_id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Qbc_idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Qbc_idField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Qbc_nameofChapter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Qbc_nameofChapterField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Qbc_nameofChapterField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int Qbc_no_of_papers
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Qbc_no_of_papersField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Qbc_no_of_papersField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int Qbc_no_of_questions
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Qbc_no_of_questionsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Qbc_no_of_questionsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Paper_Ids", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun")]
    public partial class Paper_Ids : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private int Paper_IdField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int Paper_Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Paper_IdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Paper_IdField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Qtions_data", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun")]
    public partial class Qtions_data : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private Skillgun.Answers[] AnswerField;

        private string Q_answer_choiceField;

        private string Q_answer_explainationField;

        private string Q_descField;

        private string Q_help_textField;

        private int Q_idField;

        private string Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapterField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public Skillgun.Answers[] Answer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.AnswerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.AnswerField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Q_answer_choice
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Q_answer_choiceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Q_answer_choiceField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Q_answer_explaination
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Q_answer_explainationField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Q_answer_explainationField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Q_desc
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Q_descField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Q_descField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Q_help_text
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Q_help_textField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Q_help_textField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int Q_id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Q_idField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Q_idField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapter
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapterField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapterField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Answers", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun")]
    public partial class Answers : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string ChoiceField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Choice
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ChoiceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ChoiceField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="ISkillgun_App")]
public interface ISkillgun_App
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_Names", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_NamesResponse")]
    Skillgun.ChapterNames[] Chapters_Names(string sub_topic_id);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_Names", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_NamesResponse")]
    //System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Skillgun.ChapterNames[]> Chapters_NamesAsync(string sub_topic_id);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_ids", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_idsResponse")]
    Skillgun.Paper_Ids[] Paper_ids(string chapter_id);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_ids", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_idsResponse")]
    //System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Skillgun.Paper_Ids[]> Paper_idsAsync(string chapter_id);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_data", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_dataResponse")]
    Skillgun.Qtions_data[] Qtions_data(string paper_id);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_data", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_dataResponse")]
    //System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Skillgun.Qtions_data[]> Qtions_dataAsync(string paper_id);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface ISkillgun_AppChannel : ISkillgun_App, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class Skillgun_AppClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<ISkillgun_App>, ISkillgun_App
{

    public Skillgun_AppClient()
    {
    }

    public Skillgun_AppClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public Skillgun_AppClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public Skillgun_AppClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public Skillgun_AppClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public Skillgun.ChapterNames[] Chapters_Names(string sub_topic_id)
    {
        return base.Channel.Chapters_Names(sub_topic_id);
    }

    public Skillgun.Paper_Ids[] Paper_ids(string chapter_id)
    {
        return base.Channel.Paper_ids(chapter_id);
    }

    public Skillgun.Qtions_data[] Qtions_data(string paper_id)
    {
        return base.Channel.Qtions_data(paper_id);
    }

}
```

The svc should look like below.

```
using System;
using Skillgun;

namespace WcfService1
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Skillgun_App : ISkillgun_App
    {
        public ChapterNames[] Chapters_Names(string sub_topic_id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Paper_Ids[] Paper_ids(string chapter_id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Qtions_data[] Qtions_data(string paper_id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Once that's done, run your service and go to wsdl. It should look like below.

```
<wsdl:definitions name="Skillgun_App" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun"/>
         <xs:element name="Chapters_Names">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sub_topic_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Chapters_NamesResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Chapters_NamesResult" nillable="true" type="q1:ArrayOfChapterNames" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Paper_ids">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="chapter_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Paper_idsResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Paper_idsResult" nillable="true" type="q2:ArrayOfPaper_Ids" xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Qtions_data">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="paper_id" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
         <xs:element name="Qtions_dataResponse">
            <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qtions_dataResult" nillable="true" type="q3:ArrayOfQtions_data" xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun"/>
               </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
         <xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
         <xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
         <xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
         <xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
         <xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
         <xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
         <xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
         <xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
         <xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
         <xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
         <xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
         <xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
         <xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
         <xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
         <xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
         <xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
         <xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
         <xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
         <xs:simpleType name="char">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
         <xs:simpleType name="duration">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
               <xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
               <xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
               <xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
         <xs:simpleType name="guid">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
               <xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
            </xs:restriction>
         </xs:simpleType>
         <xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
         <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
         <xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
      </xs:schema>
      <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Skillgun">
         <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfChapterNames">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ChapterNames"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ArrayOfChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfChapterNames"/>
         <xs:complexType name="ChapterNames">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_id" type="xs:int"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_nameofChapter" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_no_of_papers" type="xs:int"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbc_no_of_questions" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ChapterNames" nillable="true" type="tns:ChapterNames"/>
         <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfPaper_Ids">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Paper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:Paper_Ids"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ArrayOfPaper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPaper_Ids"/>
         <xs:complexType name="Paper_Ids">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Paper_Id" type="xs:int"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="Paper_Ids" nillable="true" type="tns:Paper_Ids"/>
         <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfQtions_data">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Qtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:Qtions_data"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ArrayOfQtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfQtions_data"/>
         <xs:complexType name="Qtions_data">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Answer" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAnswers"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_answer_choice" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_answer_explaination" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_desc" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_help_text" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Q_id" type="xs:int"/>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Qbt_hint_for_complete_chapter" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="Qtions_data" nillable="true" type="tns:Qtions_data"/>
         <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAnswers">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Answers" nillable="true" type="tns:Answers"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="ArrayOfAnswers" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAnswers"/>
         <xs:complexType name="Answers">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Choice" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
         <xs:element name="Answers" nillable="true" type="tns:Answers"/>
      </xs:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_InputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Chapters_Names"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_OutputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Chapters_NamesResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_InputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Paper_ids"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_OutputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Paper_idsResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_InputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Qtions_data"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:message name="ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_OutputMessage">
      <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Qtions_dataResponse"/>
   </wsdl:message>
   <wsdl:portType name="ISkillgun_App">
      <wsdl:operation name="Chapters_Names">
         <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_Names" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_InputMessage"/>
         <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_NamesResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Chapters_Names_OutputMessage"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="Paper_ids">
         <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_ids" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_InputMessage"/>
         <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_idsResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Paper_ids_OutputMessage"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="Qtions_data">
         <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_data" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_InputMessage"/>
         <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_dataResponse" message="tns:ISkillgun_App_Qtions_data_OutputMessage"/>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:portType>
   <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISkillgun_App" type="tns:ISkillgun_App">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
      <wsdl:operation name="Chapters_Names">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Chapters_Names" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="Paper_ids">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Paper_ids" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
      <wsdl:operation name="Qtions_data">
         <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ISkillgun_App/Qtions_data" style="document"/>
         <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:input>
         <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </wsdl:output>
      </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>
   <wsdl:service name="Skillgun_App">
      <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ISkillgun_App" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ISkillgun_App">
         <soap:address location="http://localhost:65100/Skillgun_App.svc"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Web Config..

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>    
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
      To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
      Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Sir auto generated code is added to user interface while adding reference and your  auto generated code and mine is same sir

Comment: Can i  change the wcf service sir?

Comment: Pls call me by my name (everyone in this community are equal). Yes. Change the service. You should see the bindings in your wsdl.

Comment: i changed my svc code but still i'm not getting end point information, i posted my svc code

Comment: Yes. That interface is wrong. You don't need to code your interface manually. It's already there in the generated code. Just comment your interface and use what's in the generated code.

Comment: i'm getting error as     Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.ISkillgun_App' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Comment: in app.config file no information about binding and client tags

Comment: Have a look at the new picture added to my post. I have marked the interface name in red colour. That's what you have to use.

Comment: Sounds like your web config is wrong too. I have added a web config to my reply. Just copy paste it.

Comment: i did not get any file to your reply

Comment: can you please send me one more time

Comment: It's in my reply. Just below the wsdl.

Comment: my service url is present in another application

Comment: i changed webHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding then i got end point information

Answer (score 0):

You should have had a Web.config file where the right binding information related to the default endpoint must be set. To make things easy Visual studio comes with a project template under WCF-> WCF Service Application. Use it to avoid missing any configuration steps that could lead to the problem you have stated in your question. You can focus only on your contract implementation and the rest is taken care of. Once a project of this type is created then you can see 3 important files in your Solution explorer. The IService.cs file where you will put your contract definition and implementation, then the Service.svc file which should bring up the service hosted in IIS and the Web.Config file. Your work would be to update the IService.cs file ONLY.

[image]

Then you can add a Windows Form application project under the same solution where you have this WCF service project and then add a service reference to this WinForms project by discovering the service as is shown below:

[image]

Here for sure your App.Config file will have the required endpoint configurations as shown below:

[image]

That's all. You must not be facing any issues in this approach.

[NOTE: While adding the service reference try to use the Discover option so that we avoid any mistakes that might creep in while typing the service URL.]

[image]